# How addEventListener('mousemove') recognize ctx object?

Tags: javascript

```
var d = document.getElementById('draw');
d.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
   ctx = d.getContext("2d");
   var flag = true;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = "10"
   ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
   ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);

   d.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
       if (flag == true) {
           ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
           ctx.stroke();
       }
       d.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
           flag = false;
       });
   });
});
```

I'm doing 30 days javascript challenge and have a problem with respect to the above code.
The addEventListener function('mousemove') can recognize ctx object. I thought the function cannot recognize ctx since no arguments have been passed to the function.

If I take the function out of the outer function(mousedown) and then an error occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `ctx` is a local variable within the `mousedown` nest. You're also getting the context all over again when the mouse button is pressed which is unnecesary. You have to put everything in the "global" scope prior to the first event listener.

Comment: You probably need to know how `Scope` works in JavaScript. This may help: [Scope - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).  Further more, the variable `ctx` here follows the rule of `lexical scope`.

Comment: @ChloeDev Thanks! Now I started to put everything in the global scope after taking class.

Comment: @ZmenHu Thanks.. This is what I am trying to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your variables in the same scope that the event listeners are in, your nesting was also a bit messy and I don't know how the code was functioning at all since the event listeners was nested in eachother. You also don't have to redefine the context each time you start a new path, you can use the same context as previously.

You also stroke the paths on-top of eachother without clearing it before. You can fix this on your own by either clearing the canvas before drawing the new stroke or resetting the position of the context cursor to where it is when mouse move is executed.

```js
ctx = d.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = "10"
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";

var flag = false;

d.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  
  flag = true;
});

d.addEventListener('mousemove',  function(e){
  if(!flag) return;
  
  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
  ctx.stroke();
});
  

d.addEventListener('mouseup',  function(e){
  flag = false;
});
```

Comment: The event structure is mixing of two typical drag operations. The difference is, that in the "nested construction" mousemove and mouseup events are detached in mouseup handler, whereas in the "flag-based" construction the events are attached only once.